# Why in R 1 ^ Inf = 1, instead 1 ^ Inf = NA, math rule of indeterminacy?

Tags: r, math

I have asked, why 1 ^ Inf = 1, in several lenguajes, in R for example, and other how javascript show it in correct way, in early 1 ^ Infinity = NaN, and now 1 ^ Infinity = 1 (javascript). why, some new theory?

Comment: Please cite an authority for your opinion that 1^Inf is NaN.

Comment: Continuing to claim that a computer language should adhere to your particular notions of mathematical truth, and then failing to present any coherent argument or authoritative is wasting our time. The behavior is documented and justified in the help pages that ship with every installation of R.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/10493/204734 this is the question about 1 ^ Inf equals NaN or $1 ^ \infty = \nexists$(latex), i asked about, why in R, Octave, Mathlab 1 ^ Inf equals 1 instead NaN?

Comment: My downvote is locked by the SO system until you edit the question. I would copy your comment to the body of your question and perhaps other down-voters will join me now that the source of your concern is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

From the help page:

```
?Inf
```

"The basic rule should be that calls and relations with `Inf`s really are
statements with a proper mathematical limit."

```
Lim 1^n as x -> Inf .... is == 1
```

Comment: No understand, i thought than 1 ^ Infty equals indeterminacy, same 0 divide by 0, 0 ^ 0 etc. it is not thus?

Comment: The limit of 1^n as n goes to infinity is still 1. It's about the simplest Cauchy sequence I can imagine.

Comment: Asserting that 1^Inf is an "indeterminate form" is not the same as noting that the limit of {1^n]} remains 1 at all possible values of increasing n. The analysis of the "determinacy" of a "form" is supposed to be of general assistance in the analysis of ratios of sequences of fractions and power sequences.

Answer (score -1):

> 1 ^ Infinity = 1 (javascript)

In JavaScript:

`^` is not the exponent operator, but rather the binary XOR (exclusive OR) operator, which only works on integers. Because of this, `Infinity` is interpreted to be 0 in the context of this expression. So, `1 ^ 0` (remembering that `^` is XOR) is `1`.

What I presume you want is exponentiation. This is provided by the `Math.pow()` function:

```js
> Math.pow(1, Infinity)
NaN
```

To answer your question, I believe the value of `1 ** inf` (or any other number in place of 1) is not clearly defined in IEEE 754, so languages may define them to be whatever they please. In this case, any of the values of 1, NaN and Infinity may make some logical sense.

**Disclaimer**: This is *not* an attempt at justifying that any of these values are acceptable, this simply answers the JS part of the question.

Comment: Seems pretty clear that the questioner was not really asking about JavaScript.

Comment: @BondedDust The questioner did mention JavaScript, so I figured that any misconceptions about JS here should be cleared up.

Comment: my concern is, why in R language, Matlab and Octave, 1 ^ Inf equals 1(one) when it should to be indeterminacy, above, you are right, in javascript, i can to use the pow function Math.pow(1, Infinity) equals NA(indeterminacy), but  i repeat my concern is about the this results R,  Octave and Matlab, somebody explain me there?

Comment: I've explained the rationale. If you do not understand the notion of limits of infinite sequences, then that is just a deficiency in your mathematical education that you will need to address some other place. This is a forum about coding. The fact that computer languages are different is not evidence of error but rather differences in convention. Javascript would NOT be _my_ first resource if I were trying to present arguments about mathematical concepts.

Comment: Sorry BondeDust, i seen your answer, thanks, yea this is a place of sources, and i know that R, Matlab and Octave are programming languages too, You're very kind, please do you have some link where i understand more about of Cauchy sequence please! :)

Comment: Sorry @auscompgeek, thank for your answer, i am going to research about IEEE 754